# lambda function to compare two consecutive rows in a dataframe and create a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe  `df['y0', 'size]` as two columns in it.

y0 has float values from 25.0 to 800.0
size is a float datatype, which has values from 8 to 25.

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
y0    Size
25    8  
37    8.7  
68.5  9.3  
93.4  11.4  
110.7  14.6  
145.6  12.1  
180.3  10.9'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
```

and so on...

**Desired output**
create a new column [y0Dash], which has this logic:

```
MIN_Y0_DIFF = 0.3

if ((df['y0'] - df[['y0'].shift(-1)]) /
           ((df['Size'] + df[['Size'].shift(-1)]) / 2) < MIN_Y0_DIFF) ):
    df['y0Dash'] = df['y0']
else:
    df['y0Dash'] = df['y0'].shift(-1)
```

I get the error that I am trying to compare a scalar value with a series, which I understand - I am trying to compare with MIN_Y0_DIFF.

But, I am not getting how to do this in a lambda function. How compare two consecutive rows to get my desired result?

**What I tried**

```
def columnCompare():  
    if ((df['y0'] - df[['y0'].shift(-1)]) /
               ((df['Size'] + df[['Size'].shift(-1)]) / 2) < MIN_Y0_DIFF) ):
        df['y0Dash'] = df['y0']
    else:
        df['y0Dash'] = df['y0'].shift(-1)


df = df.apply(lambda x: columnCompare)
```

Comment: Hey! Nice to see that you tried. Can you put your logic into words or maybe an expected output?

Comment: Please post your desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use a `lambda` function for this. If I understand your logic correctly, you can calculate a Boolean mask and apply your logic in a vectorised fashion.

It seems the main problem is how you are attempting to implement `pd.Series.shift`: `df[['Size'].shift(-1)]` is incorrect as `list` does not have a `shift` method.

```
MIN_Y0_DIFF = 0.3
mask = (df['y0'] - df['y0'].shift(-1)) / \
       ((df['Size'] + df['Size'].shift(-1)) / 2) < MIN_Y0_DIFF

df.loc[mask, 'y0Dash'] = df['y0']
df.loc[~mask, 'y0Dash'] = df['y0'].shift(-1)
```

Result:

```
      y0  Size  y0Dash
0   25.0   8.0    25.0
1   37.0   8.7    37.0
2   68.5   9.3    68.5
3   93.4  11.4    93.4
4  110.7  14.6   110.7
5  145.6  12.1   145.6
6  180.3  10.9     NaN
```